# POST using mysql and nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, authentication, post

I've been working on a registration route, on a express server, using coffeescript.

Here is what i've done so far:

```
app.post '/register', (req, res, next) ->
  email = req.body.email
  username = req.body.username
  password = req.body.password
  checkEmailUsernameExists(email, username).then((rows) ->
    if rows.length = 0
      console.log 'if'
      console.log rows.length
      createAccount email, username, password
    else
      console.log 'else'
      console.log rows.length
      res.send {'success': false, 'message': 'Email or username already registered!'}
    ).catch((err) ->
      throw err
      return
    )

createAccount = (mail, user, pass) ->
  query = "INSERT INTO users (email, username, password) VALUES (" + mail + "," + user + "," + pass + ")"
  bcrypt.genSalt 10, (err, salt) ->
    bcrypt.hash pass, salt, (err, hash) ->
      # Store hashed password in DB.
      connection.query query, (err, res) ->
        if err
          res.status(500).json { error: err }
        res.send {'success': true, 'message': 'Account registration success!'}

checkEmailUsernameExists = (mail, user) ->
  return new Promise (resolve, reject) ->
    query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ? OR username = ?"
    connection.query query, [mail, user], (err, row, fields) ->
      if err
        reject err
      resolve row
```

Problem is: DB is empty, and every time i POST to the route, i get the following console output:

> else 0 POST /register 200 1.313 ms - 67

Shouldn't i be getting:

> if 0 POST /register 200 1.313 ms - 67 
>   ?
>   Thank you for your patience.

Comment: You do not compare, you assign a value to `0`.i.e. `rows.length = 0`. You need `==` or `===`.

Comment: Thanks, i just saw that.